# Why my react footer is overlapping with my existing widgets?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have created react components as shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarterScreen from './components/screens/StarterScreen.jsx';
import LoginScreen from './components/screens/LoginScreen.jsx';
import RegisterScreen from './components/screens/RegisterScreen.jsx';
import DisplayScreen from './components/screens/DisplayScreen.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Footer from './components/junk/Footer';
//import LineChart from './components/coreComponents/LineChart.js';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/security/PrivateRoute.jsx';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  function App(){
    return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={RegisterScreen} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={LoginScreen} exact path="/login"></Route>
    <ProtectedRoute component={DisplayScreen} exact path="/login-props-test" />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
    }

export default App;
```

For the pages which don't extend till the end, footer looks decent, but for the pages which extend to bottom, footer actually overlaps. Can someone tell me the reason for the same? What's the best possible way to avoid such problems?

Here is the footer script:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Footer()
{
    const Element1 = "GZB Automation";
    const today = new Date();
    const DayFormat = today.toString().split(" ").slice(0,4);
    const Element3 = DayFormat.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
    console.log(Element3);
    const Element2 = "Copyright © "+today.getFullYear().toString()+". All rights reserved.";
    return(
        <div className="FooterAligner">
        <div className="FooterElement Footer01">{Element1}</div>
        <div className="FooterElement">{Element2}</div>
        <div className="FooterElement Footer03">{Element3}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the css for same, what I observe is that when I keep `css property` `position` as  `fixed` then this overlap happens and when I keep it to  `inherit`, it moves to the top as shown below:

[image]

```
.FooterAligner
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.FooterElement
{
  width: calc(100%/3);
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1B4855;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

Here's the screenshot for the same:

When the content is less:

[image]

When the content covers the entire screen space:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need the Footer within the BrowserRouter, but your problem is more likely due to CSS rather the React code.

Comment: Hi @jmargolisvt thanks for the suggestion added footer and it's css as well.

Comment: You would need to add more CSS to really know --specifically how your container manages its top-level children-- but I think you're going to find that including the Footer in that strategy,  and adding min-heights will help you.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion @jmargolisvt